# How to provide Role based Login and Menu in MVC3?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

my task is to provide role based menu to the users.....this is the first time i am practically working on MVC3 so expecting your help....
I am geing the roles from the database...

so i have different menus like this [Home],[About],[Projects],[SetUP],[Resources] and like this what i wan to do is when an user wiht role [admin] logs in i have to provide him with [Home],[About],[SetUP] menus only,how can i do this can any one help me in doing this briefly.....
this is what i did till now
how will i get the role name from role id in the tables....i had created a login where i dnt use role based now how can i provide role based login

this is my LoginModel Class

```
      public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid(string _username, string _pwd)
    {

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LMIT-0039;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True");
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetRoleName", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName ", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _username;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _pwd;
        Object TypeUser = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        cn.Close();
        if (TypeUser != null)
        {
            if (TypeUser.ToString() == "Admin")
                return true;
            else if (TypeUser.ToString() == "Developer")
                return true;
            else if (TypeUser.ToString() == "QA")
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

can any one help me in doing this please....

Comment: Do you know the story of the boy called [`Bobby Tables`](http://bobby-tables.com/)? If you don't want this story to be your story, please use parametrized queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built in Forms authentication you can access users roles like this:

```
string userRole = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

I used the `FirstOrDefault` because a user could have more than one role. From here you can use a `switch` statement to return the related view. Also if you want to hide items (like menu items in the global layout,) you can do this:

```
@if(Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault() == "TheRoleYouWant")
{
    ...
}
```

Also you can add an `Authorize` attribute to a function in a controller (or the entire controller) that will only allow users with this role to access it. Like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Role2, Role3")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Note that you can add more than one role, they just need to be comma separated like above.

There are a lot of other options, like `IsUserInRole("Admin")`, take a look at [Implementing a Role Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx).